# Compound adjectives

Tags: meaning

What does "community-maintained artifacts of lasting value" in this passage? What is the role of 'of'?

> Many online communities are emerging that, like Wikipedia, bring
>   people together to build **community-maintained artifacts of lasting
>   value** (CALVs). Motivating people to contribute is a key problem
>   because ...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are asking if this is "grammatically correct" when it's from an abstract from a [published paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.65.10). What makes you think there would be any kind of "grammatical" problem with the phrase? I have no problem with anyone saying, "I'm having trouble understanding what this means," but questioning grammaticality seems very out-of-place. I suggest taking a look at [this meta post](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), and then editing your question to tell us what you are _really_ asking about.

Comment: @J.R. Do you really thinks all published papers are error-free!?

Comment: No, but published papers tend to have a much lower error rate than, say, a blog. Moreover, I think it's unacceptable to copy-and-paste large pieces of text and ask "Is this grammatically correct?" without identifying WHY you think there might be an error. For example: `Is "look on the bright side of life" grammatical correct? I would think it would be "look AT the bright side" instead` would be on-topic, because the source of confusion is pinpointed. However, `Is "Look on the bright side of life" grammatically correct?` by itself is very much **NOT** on topic, because we don't proofread here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *artifact* is referring to some written piece of information that can be referred to later. Although the word *artifact* often refers to some ancient cultural relic, the word need not always be used in this manner. Consider [this definition](http://www.wordnik.com/words/artifact):

> **artifact** (*n.*) any product of human workmanship; – applied both to objects made for practical purposes as well as works of art. It is contrasted to *natural object*, i.e. anything produced by natural forces without the intervention of man.

An **artifact of lasting value**, then, refers to an artifact that people will find useful sometime down the road. The Stack Exchange network strives to create artifacts of lasting value, which is why its members are encouraged to make sure questions are well-written and remain on-topic. In the world of art, the *Mona Lisa* is considered a work of lasting value, but my daughter's third grade finger painting is not (the third grade finger painting may have much *sentimental* value, but it doesn't have lasting cultural value).

A **community-maintained artifact of lasting value**, then, simply refers to some useful source of information that is maintained by a community, rather than by a single agency, caretaker, or curator. Wikipedia – mentioned by name in the abstract – is perhaps the quintessential CALV: it is visited by millions (so it apparently has lasting value). Morevoer, it was built by unpaid experts – it was built by a community, and is being maintained by a community.

Comment: So is it true to say "community-maintained lasting-value artifacts"? It seems the "of" is used two assign an compound adjective to a noun. Can you please name some similar examples?

Comment: I prefer the original wording; compound adjectives can be clunky – particularly when they are doubled up like that, but even when they're not. Examples? How about [_people of high integrity_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=people+of+high+integrity%2Chigh+integrity+people%2Chigh-integrity+people&year_start=1965&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeople%20of%20high%20integrity%3B%2Cc0) or [_disease of unknown origin_](https://www.google.com/#q=%22disease+of+unknown+origin%22&safe=off&tbm=bks).